# Can you use pine script in trading view to autotrade Tradovate futures?

Tags: algorithm, pine-script

I have a pine script written that I am able to back test.  Now I just want to setup an autotrading bot to trade futures 24/5 in Tradovate.  Is there a platform to link the 2?  I already have the ability to manual execute trades on Tradovate in Trading view (so they are linked).  I just need to automate my script.

Tradovate will not release their API to anyone other than their partners.

Answer (score 0):

if they don't have an api you can access, then sounds like the answer is no